# What norms, instructions, permissions and customs are there that do not conform to Traditionis Custodes?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, traditionis-custodes

This bullet point in *[Tradionis Custodes](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html)* has me super confused:

> Art 8. Previous norms, instructions, permissions, and customs that do not conform to the provisions of the present Motu Proprio are abrogated.

And I can't watch enough Dr. Taylor Marshal podcasts to find this out.  I went to two Latin Masses this weekend for a Troops of St. George Assembly and noticed that the two different priests closed the Mass differently.  Which got me thinking, if something like Pope Leo XIII's St. Michael Prayer is customarily prayed in some parishes or a few Hail Mary's or anything of the sort, are this customs canned in favor of strict adherence to the 1962 missal (except the part where the readings are in the vernacular)?

Comment: "_are this customs canned in favor of strict adherence to the 1962 missal_". The Leonine Prayers are not part of the Mass.

Comment: @geremia, while the edit was appreciated, redacting my question doesn't help me that much.  If the premise is wrong, I'd rather get that as an answer.  I'd rather edit the title if you'd prefer to answer the question you redacted it to?  I was just pointing to one example that I thought was a custom.

Comment: It seemed to me you were asking two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

**What norms, instructions, permissions and customs are there that do not conform to [*Traditionis Custodes*](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html)?**

God Bless me if I am wrong, and it is not my intention or interpretation to anything involved in this subject matter, but a ton of clarity on behalf of Pope Francis is needed in this domain!

Before going on with the in and outs of this question, this is clearly a matter that could involve yet another serious ***dubium***.

Latin is the official language of the Vatican, yet a Latin version in not offered on the Vatican website at present. It may in fact have been written in Italian. [***Quelle surprise***!](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quelle+surprise)

The raw data has not been disclosed.

> [*Inter mirifica*](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19631204_inter-mirifica_en.html), is the Vatican II Decree on the Means of Social Communication, recognized the right to information:
>
> > There exists therefore in human society a right to information on the subjects that are of concern to men either as individuals or as members of society, according to each man’s circumstances. The proper exercise of this right demands that the content of the communication be true and—within the limits set by justice and charity—complete. [§5]
>
> The context of this Decree was the practice of the media in general (especially the news media) and also more broadly the growing sense that the Church and individual Catholics should make increased use of the means of social communication. In 1964, Pope St. Paul VI transformed an existing commission on cinema, radio, and television into the Pontifical Commission for Social Communications, and in the years following Vatican II, this Commission would develop further the Council’s teaching on the media and on the right to information.
>
> In 1971, the Pontifical Commission issued [*Communio et Progressio*](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/pccs/documents/rc_pc_pccs_doc_23051971_communio_en.html), in which it recalled that John XXIII, Paul VI, and Vatican II all had recognized a right to information [§33]. This right is connected to man’s social nature, and it is important not only for the individual, but also for the public interest [§35]. Moreover, in 1992, the office (now a Pontifical Council) declared in *Aetatis novae* that this right to information applies not only in secular society, but in the Church as well:
>
> > [I]t is necessary constantly to recall the importance of the fundamental right of dialogue and information within the church, as described in Communio et Progressio, and to continue to seek effective means, including a responsible use of media of social communications, for realizing and protecting this right. [§10]
>
> In addition, in a 2000 document on [*Ethics in Communication*](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/pccs/documents/rc_pc_pccs_doc_20000530_ethics-communications_en.html), the Pontifical Council warned against the demonization of others [§13] and—specifically in the religious context—noted the need to avoid **“practicing unnecessary secrecy and otherwise offending against truth”** [§18].
>
> [***Traditionis custodes* and the raw data on the Latin Mass**](https://www.catholicworldreport.com/2021/07/19/traditionis-custodes-and-the-raw-data-of-the-latin-mass/)

Cardinal Burke, in my opinion, seems to imply that **all liturgical norms, instructions, permissions and customs of Pope St. John Paul II the Great and Pope St. Paul VI do not conform with *Traditionis Custodes***!

> 17. Pope Francis states in his [letter to the Bishops](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/letters/2021/documents/20210716-lettera-vescovi-liturgia.html): “Responding to your requests, I take the firm decision to abrogate all the norms, instructions, permissions and customs that precede the present Motu proprio, and declare that the liturgical books promulgated by the saintly Pontiffs Paul VI and John Paul II, in conformity with the decrees of Vatican Council II, constitute the unique [only] expression of the lex orandi of the Roman Rite.” The total abrogation in question, in justice, requires that each individual norm, instruction, permission and custom be studied, to verify that it “contradicts communion and nurtures the divisive tendency … against which the Apostle Paul so vigorously reacted.” - [Statement on the Motu Proprio «*Traditionis Custodes*»](https://www.cardinalburke.com/presentations/traditionis-custodes)

I believe that this is a can of worms that Pope Francis wished he had never opened!

Comment: I diffed the English translations between the release and now and the only differences are "Official translation" was added to the page.  I wonder if that was for the people, like me, who thought at first it was just a bad translation...